# Spring, JPA, Hibernate: how to prevent an object's timestamp from be changed

Tags: java, nhibernate, jpa

I have a Spring + JPA (Hibernate) web application.

I have a class which has the following field:

```
private Date updatedTime;

@Version
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getUpdatedTime() {
    return updatedTime;
}

public void setUpdatedTime(Date lastUpdatedTime) {
    this.updatedTime = lastUpdatedTime;
}
```

In a transactional method in the service layer, I need to load an instance of this class and modify it before replicating (via XStream) all its properties to a new instance of the same class (I have to follow this order because I don't want to replicate some unwanted big data fields (Collection fields, which contains "detailed" objects unique to each instance of that class) in the old instance to the new one). When the new instance is saved to the database, the method returns. Now the updatedTime field of the old instance gets updated. How can I prevent it from happening?

Thanks for help!

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JPA supports using an optimistic locking version field that gets
>   updated on each update. The field can either be numeric or a timestamp
>   value. **A numeric value is recommended as a numeric value is more
>   precise, portable, performant and easier to deal with than a
>   timestamp.**

As specified in documentation, the version field gets updated implicitly. You can have a separate field in the entity as version, as there is dependency on timestamp field & to restrict it from updation.

---

**Edit :**

Optimistic locking allows concurrent transactions & tracks changes based on the version field & it is updated along with the entity.

Before transaction commit, the version field is checked whether it has been changed by other transaction, since the entity was read.

`UPDATE ENTITY SET ..., version = version+1 WHERE version = previousVersion`

Lock mode `PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` & `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` will force the version field to increment.

Pessimistic locking locks the database row while fetching entity from database.

Specify lock mode as `OPTIMISTIC`, `PESSIMISTIC_READ`, `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` which will not update version field.

- You can have a extra dedicated field for the version, other than required fields.
- Else, can specify appropriate locking mode to prevent version field from getting updated.

Comment: Hi Nayan, thanks so much for chiming in. I will consider using a numeric value for the version field. But my intention is preventing the version field from getting updated in my situation. Will the numeric version field be updated or not in the my situation? What do you mean by "there is dependency on timestamp field & to restrict it from updation." ? Thanks, again!

Comment: @curious1 I have updated post with additional information, refer edit part.